# TensorFlow: getting variable by name

Tags: tensorflow

When using the TensorFlow Python API, I created a variable (without specifying its `name` in the constructor), and its `name` property had the value `"Variable_23:0"`.  When I try to select this variable using `tf.get_variable("Variable23")`, a new variable called `"Variable_23_1:0"` is created instead. How do I correctly select `"Variable_23"` instead of creating a new one?

What I want to do is select the variable by name, and reinitialize it so I can finetune weights.

Answer (score 40):

The `get_variable()` function creates a new variable or returns one created earlier by `get_variable()`. It won't return a variable created using `tf.Variable()`. Here's a quick example:

```
>>> with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
...   bar1 = tf.get_variable("bar", (2,3)) # create
... 
>>> with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
...   bar2 = tf.get_variable("bar")  # reuse
... 

>>> with tf.variable_scope("", reuse=True): # root variable scope
...   bar3 = tf.get_variable("foo/bar") # reuse (equivalent to the above)
... 
>>> (bar1 is bar2) and (bar2 is bar3)
True
```

If you did not create the variable using `tf.get_variable()`, you have a couple options. First, you can use `tf.global_variables()` (as @mrry suggests):

```
>>> bar1 = tf.Variable(0.0, name="bar")
>>> bar2 = [var for var in tf.global_variables() if var.op.name=="bar"][0]
>>> bar1 is bar2
True
```

Or you can use `tf.get_collection()` like so:

```
>>> bar1 = tf.Variable(0.0, name="bar")
>>> bar2 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="bar")[0]
>>> bar1 is bar2
True
```

**Edit**

You can also use `get_tensor_by_name()`:

```
>>> bar1 = tf.Variable(0.0, name="bar")
>>> graph = tf.get_default_graph()
>>> bar2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("bar:0")
>>> bar1 is bar2
False, bar2 is a Tensor througn convert_to_tensor on bar1. but bar1 equal 
bar2 in value.
```

Recall that a tensor is the output of an operation. It has the same name as the operation, plus `:0`. If the operation has multiple outputs, they have the same name as the operation plus `:0`, `:1`, `:2`, and so on.

Comment: can you explain what happened here? didnt work for me

Comment: @Matian2040 I improved my answer, hopefully it should be clear now. :)

Answer (score 37):

The easiest way to get a variable by name is to search for it in the [`tf.global_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables) collection:

```
var_23 = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name == "Variable_23:0"][0]
```

This works well for ad hoc reuse of existing variables. A more structured approach—for when you want to share variables between multiple parts of a model—is covered in the [Sharing Variables tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html#sharing-variables).

Comment: can you provide an example with the sharing variable thing? It keeps asking me to reuse and I understand what that means, but I can't get tensorflow to work.

Comment: UPDATE:WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-57-20363f0171a3>:1 in <module>.: all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating:
Please use tf.global_variables instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have a different situation. Could you please tell me can I use `get_tensor_by_name` or `get variable by name` to get something defined by `tf.layers.dense`, e.g., `means` in this code sample [here](https://gist.github.com/Erichliu00/1ce345e548b31cf1f2a6efed34ba9dec).

Comment: Is their a better way not to iterate all created ops and use a key instead?

Comment: Link is dead. too old ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any stored variables from a model, use`tf.train.load_variable("model_folder_name","Variable name")`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @mrry 's answer, I think it would be better to create and use the following function, since there's also local variables, and other variables that are not in global variables (they are in different collections):

```
def get_var_by_name(query_name, var_list):
    """
    Get Variable by name

    e.g.
    local_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES)
    the_var = get_var_by_name(local_vars, 'accuracy/total:0')
    """
    target_var = None
    for var in var_list:
        if var.name==query_name:
            target_var = var
            break
    return target_var
```