# Restoring Tensorflow model and viewing variable value

Tags: tensorflow

I declared the some Tensorflow variables representing weights and biases and updated their values in training before saving them, as shown:

```
#                # 5 x 5 x 5 patches, 1 channel, 32 features to compute.
weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,1,32]), name='w_conv1'),
           #       5 x 5 x 5 patches, 32 channels, 64 features to compute.
           'W_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,32,64]), name='w_conv2'),
           #                                  64 features
           'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32448,1024]), name='w_fc'), #54080 = ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(10/2/2) * 64
           #'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([54080,1024]), name='W_fc'), #54080 = ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(20/2/2) * 64
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]), name='w_out')}

biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]), name='b_conv1'),
           'b_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]), name='b_conv2'),
           'b_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]), name='b_fc'),
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]), name='b_out')}

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    #some training code

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, 'my-save-dir/my-model-10')
```

Then, I tried restoring the model and accessing the variables as shown below:

```
weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape=False, name='w_conv1'),
           #       5 x 5 x 5 patches, 32 channels, 64 features to compute.
           'W_conv2':tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape=False, name='w_conv2'),
           #                                  64 features
           'W_fc':tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape=False, name='w_fc'), #54080 = ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(10/2/2) * 64
           #'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([54080,1024]), name='W_fc'), #54080 = ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(20/2/2) * 64
           'out':tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape=False, name='w_out')}

biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape=False, name='b_conv1'),
           'b_conv2':tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape=False, name='b_conv2'),
           'b_fc':tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape=False, name='b_fc'),
           'out':tf.Variable(-1.0, validate_shape=False, name='b_out')}

with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my-save-dir/my-model-10.meta')
    model_saver.restore(sess, "my-save-dir/my-model-10")
    print("Model restored.") 
    print('Initialized')
    print(sess.run(weights['W_conv1']))
```

However, I got a "FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value w_conv1". Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happens in your second code snippet: you first create all the variables `w_conv1` to `b_out`, so the default graph is populated with the respective nodes. Then you call `import_meta_graph(..)` where again the default graph is populated with all the nodes from the model you stored in your first code snippet. However, for every node it tries to load, another node with the same name already exists (because you created it "by hand" just before). I don't know what happens internally in this case, but taking a look at the output of `tf.global_variables()` after the call to `import_meta_graph(..)` reveals that now every node exists twice with exactly the same name. So restoring is probably undefined and it might just restore half of the variables which is why you see this error.

So, you have two possibilites to solve this:

**1) Don't use `import_from_metagraph`**

```
weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,1,32]), name='w_conv1'),
           #       5 x 5 x 5 patches, 32 channels, 64 features to compute.
           'W_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,32,64]), name='w_conv2'),
           #                                  64 features
           'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32448,1024]), name='w_fc'), #54080 = ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(10/2/2) * 64
           #'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([54080,1024]), name='W_fc'), #54080 = ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(50/2/2) * ceil(20/2/2) * 64
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]), name='w_out')}

biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]), name='b_conv1'),
           'b_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]), name='b_conv2'),
           'b_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]), name='b_fc'),
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]), name='b_out')}

with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_saver = tf.train.Saver()
    model_saver.restore(sess, "my-save-dir/my-model-10")
    print("Model restored.")
    print('Initialized')
    print(sess.run(weights['W_conv1']))
```

**2) Use `import_from_metagraph` but don't recreate the graph from hand**

So, just this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my-save-dir/my-model-10.meta')
    model_saver.restore(sess, "my-save-dir/my-model-10")
    print("Model restored.") 
    print('Initialized')
    print(sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('w_conv1:0')))
```

Note how in this case you need to change how you retrieve the value in 'w_conv1' (last line). Instead of calling `get_tensor_by_name()` you could also use `tf.get_variable()`, but for this to work, you have to create the variables already by using `tf.get_variable()`. Check this post for more details: [TensorFlow: getting variable by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678883/tensorflow-getting-variable-by-name)