# Tenorflow load model error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to load a previous saved TENSOFLOW model (both graph and variables).

Here's how I exported the model during the training session

```
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

for batch_index in range(batch_size):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = sample_dataframe(train_df, N=batch_size)
    #print(batch_xs.shape)
    #print(batch_ys.shape)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x: batch_xs, y_:batch_ys})

    if batch_index % 100 == 0:
        print("Batch "+str(batch_index))
        correct_predictions = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, tf.float32))
        print("Accuracy: "+str(sess.run(accuracy,
                                                  feed_dict = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})))
        #print("Predictions "+str(y))
        #print("Training accuracy: %.1f%%" %accuracy())
    if batch_index + 1 == batch_size:
        #Save the trained model
        print("Exporting trained model")
        builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(EXPORT_DIR)
        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ['simple-MNIST'])
        builder.save(as_text=True)
```

Please ignore how the model is defined (it's just a toy example), and check only the last lines where the save method is invoked. Everything went fine and the model is correctly saved in the FS.

When I try lo load the exported model I always get the following error:

> TypeError: Can not convert a MetaGraphDef into a Tensor or Operation.

Here's how I load the model:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(tf.saved_model.loader.maybe_saved_model_directory(export_dir))
  saved_model = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['simple-MNIST'], export_dir)

  sess.run(saved_model)
```

Any idea how to solve it? It seems that the model has been exported with a wrong format, but I can't figure out how to change it.

Here's a simple script for load the model and scoring it.

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape =(batch_size, 784))
  W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(784, 10), stddev=0.1))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 10))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

  print(tf.saved_model.loader.maybe_saved_model_directory(export_dir))
  saved_model = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['simple-MNIST'], export_dir)

  batch_xs, batch_ys = sample_dataframe(train_df, N=batch_size)
  y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
  correct_predictions = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, tf.float32))    

 print("Test Accuracy: "+ str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})))
```

Running this script in a brand new PYTHON context, will score the model with a very low accuracy (it seems that the load model method hasn't correctly set the graph variables)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you cannot pass `saved_model` into `sess.run`. From the documentation of `saved_model.loader.load`:

> Returns:
>       The `MetaGraphDef` protocol buffer loaded in the provided session. This
>       can be used to further extract signature-defs, collection-defs, etc.

So, what exactly would you expect from `sess.run(saved_model)` when `saved_model` is a `MetaGraphDef`? If I've understood the mechanics of `load` correctly, then the graph as well as the associated variables are restored in the session you pass to `load(..)` and hence your model is ready to use once `load(..)` finished. So you should be able to access variables, ops and tensors through the (default) graph as usual and there is no need to further deal with the returned `MetaGraphDef` object.

Here is more information about what a `MetaGraphDef` is: [What is the TensorFlow checkpoint meta file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195454/what-is-the-tensorflow-checkpoint-meta-file). From this it should be clear that it does not make sense to use it with `sess.run()`.

**Edit**

Following up on your edit: The function `tf.saved_model.loader.load` internally calls `tf.import_meta_graph` followed by `saver.restore`, i.e. it restores both the graph *and* the values of the variables present in the graph. Thus, it should not be necessary for you to redefine the variables yourself in the beginning of the code snippet you added. In fact, it might cause undefined behavior as then some nodes might exist twice in the default graph. Check this stackoverflow post for more info: [Restoring Tensorflow model and viewing variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014271/restoring-tensorflow-model-and-viewing-variable-value/43018033#43018033). So I guess what is happening here is: the inference step uses the untrained variable `W` that you created manually instead of the pretrained one that you load through `saved_model.loader`, which is why you see the low accuracy.

So, my guess is that if you omit the definitions of `x`, `W`, `b` and `y_` in the beginning and retrieve them from the restored graph e.g. through calling `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('variable_name'))` it should work fine.

PS: If you are restoring a model there is no need to run the initializer (even though I assume it doesn't hurt either).

PPS: In your script you are computing the accuracy 'by hand', but I would assume that this operation is already present in the model as it is most likely needed during training as well, no? So instead of calculating the accuracy from hand again, you could just fetch the respective node from the graph and use that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you're right, but I'm still struggling in finding a solution. 
I tried to load the model into a separate notebook, but the variables seems to be uninitialized (I also hado to redifined them in order to make the code functional).
If I load the model in the same context (notebook in this case), the model scores new entries correctly, but not when I try to load it in a brand new notebook.

Comment: What do you want to do with the model once it is loaded (continue training, use it for inference, retrieve some specific variables/tensors ...)?

Comment: I want to use it for inference new entries. When I save the model I consider it as complete. Thank you again!

Comment: Could you edit your post with a reproducible example of that error you are describing?

Comment: Everything is getting more clear! Unfortunately I'm still not able to load the tenors defined in the graph. When I try to load tensor W  (tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('W')) I get the following error: "The name 'W' looks like an (invalid) Operation name, not a Tensor. Tensor names must be of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>". I think I had to map tensors in the graph before saving, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139869/discussion-between-kaufmanu-and-luke035).