# tensorflow restore only some variables from checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

After inspecting a checkpoint (let's call it model 1) I obtained the following list of variable names in it (shortened for simplicity):

```
var_list = ["ex1_model/fc2/b",
"ex1_model/fc2/b/Adam",
"ex1_model/fc2/b/Adam_1",
"ex1_model/fc2/w",
"ex1_model/fc2/w/Adam"]
```

Suppose I have a much bigger model 2 and want to initialize parts of it with the values from model 1.

[Obtain variables from names as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678883/tensorflow-getting-variable-by-name) (because I didn't find an easy way to do it):

```
def get_vars_by_name(names):
    return [v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name in names]
```

Build model 2 and a saver to restore:

```
logits = build_model(inputs)
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=get_vars_by_name(var_list))
```

At

```
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoints_dir))
```

I receive the error:

```
"ex1_model/fc2/w/Adam" [...] raise ValueError("No variables to save")
```

Please help me find the mistake I made. I'd also be grateful for a simpler way because this is terrible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An simple way to solve is this issue would be to guess if the variable should be restored or not.

```py
def ignore_name(name):
    if name.endswith('/Adam') or name.endswith('/Adam_1'):
        return True
    return False
```

You should be able to use this idea directly via

```py
def get_vars_by_name(names):
    return [v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name in names and not ignore_name(v.name)]
```

This even allows to train the model using ADAM and later switch to SDG or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The Adam is not the problem. If I remove it from the list I get the same error on "ex1_model/fc2/w" and so on.